# Related to Mule API

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am facing the below issue , Please help.

Post deploying Mulesoft program to API Management .We have xml input and xml schema to validate it .For xml API we are getting the following error .

```
Schema could not be resolved for key : **/mytask/edit-application/detail
,POST application/xml (org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException)
org.mule.module.apikit.validation.RestXmlSchemaValidator: 80**
```

Thanks